# New to Linux - ISO image size

Tags: iso, dvd, cd

The ISO I downloaded is 708 MB - too big for a CD, so I'm required to burn it to a DVD, or will it fit?

Comment: See the above links. To be honest, I have not "burned" a CD or DVD to test or install linux in years. Flash drives are inexpensive, recyclable, and allow you to store data (in addition to running live / installing).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a bit to big for a CD but you could also use a USB device to install ubuntu using [uNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).